Custom domain not working with AWS Application Load Balancer
We have a webapp in ECS fargate cluster. I am exposing it through an application load balancer, Now I have a swagger UI to test my endpoints so I access it through (load balancer url):8080/swagger/index.html. (Which works alright with HTTP)
What I need help with is using my custom domain name xyz.com (hosted by domain.com) to be used instead of load balancer url. I also need it to be https.
I have changed the name servers for the domain to be Route 53 in AWS. I have successfully generated and validated SSL certificates for my domain and subdomains.
For that to work with my load balancer I made an A record in route 53 that has an Alias record to load balancer.
When I got to xyz.com, I saw the url is secure and has HTTPS confirming that I have the ssl cert config working. But when I go to xyz.com/swagger/index.html, I get a blank page (upon using the inspect tool, I get 404 not found).
My web app is exposed at port 8080, and I have 2 listeners on my load balancers for port 8080 and 443 both are forwarding to the same target group for port 8080 (that works with the ELB url) and health checks also passing.
How can we make changes to get the xyz.com to work with the swagger ui page. I have spent weeks without any resolution. Feel free to ask me for more info or any code / config.

What do your ecs logs show? Does it show your service being hit when you go to the url? What about if you run nslookup xyz.com/swagger/index.html Does it show you the correct ip address for your load balancer?

I wrote a CDK pattern on serverlessland on similar topic. You can checkout that https://serverlessland.com/patterns/route53-alb-fargate-cdk-dotnet, also refer the README on the GitHub for the same pattern.

If you are getting a 404 then your web server is receiving the request, but it doesn't know how to serve anything at the /swagger/index.html path. Check your ECS container's logs. This is not an issue with the load balancer. Are you sure that path is configured correctly in y our docker image? What happens when you run the same docker image locally? Can you access that path locally?
